# Jsonp function callback does not recognized

Tags: javascript, jsonp

I'm trying to implement this jsonp function. But the callback function does not work, here is the function.

```js
function jsonp(url, callback) {
    var callbackName = 'jsonp_callback_' + Math.round(100000 * Math.random());
    window[callbackName] = function(data) {
        delete window[callbackName];
        document.body.removeChild(script);
        callback(data);
    };

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url + (url.indexOf('?') >= 0 ? '&' : '?') + 'callback=' + callbackName;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

jsonp('http://www.helloword.com', function(data) {
   alert(data);
});
```

The url is triggered but I want to manipulate data inside the callback function.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Its seems that I need a valid url to call, I was testing with a random url.

```js
function jsonp(url, callback) {
    var callbackName = 'jsonp_callback_' + Math.round(100000 * Math.random());
        
    window[callbackName] = function(data) {
        delete window[callbackName];
        document.body.removeChild(script);
        callback(data);
    };

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url + (url.indexOf('?') >= 0 ? '&' : '?') + 'callback=' + callbackName;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

var el = document.getElementById('clickme');

el.addEventListener('click',function(e){

jsonp('http://www.telize.com/jsonip', function(data) {
   console.debug(data);
});

});
```